# C# Sharepoint upload large file into subfolder

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an issue when trying too upload a large file to a sub sharepoint folder.
The issue is related to the variable `libraryName`. I am not sure have i can change this so i can use an url instead.

Example:
var site = ""https://sharepoint.com/sites/Test_Site1/"

var relative = "Documents/Folder1/folder2/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint

```
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File UploadFileSlicePerSlice(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string fileName, int fileChunkSizeInMB = 3)
{
  // Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
  Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();

  // Get the name of the file.
  string uniqueFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

  // Ensure that target library exists, and create it if it is missing.
  if (!LibraryExists(ctx, ctx.Web, libraryName))
  {
    CreateLibrary(ctx, ctx.Web, libraryName);
  }
  // Get the folder to upload into.
  List docs = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
  ctx.Load(docs, l => l.RootFolder);
  // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
  ctx.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();

  // File object.
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = null;

  // Calculate block size in bytes.
  int blockSize = fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024;

  // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
  ctx.Load(docs.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();


  // Get the size of the file.
  long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;

  if (fileSize <= blockSize)
  {
    // Use regular approach.
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
      FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
      fileInfo.ContentStream = fs;
      fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
      fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
      uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
      ctx.Load(uploadFile);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
      return uploadFile;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Use large file upload approach.
    ClientResult<long> bytesUploaded = null;

    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
      fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
      using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
      {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
        Byte[] lastBuffer = null;
        long fileoffset = 0;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;
        bool first = true;
        bool last = false;

        // Read data from file system in blocks.
        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
          totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

          // You've reached the end of the file.
          if (totalBytesRead == fileSize)
          {
            last = true;
            // Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
            lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
          }

          if (first)
          {
            using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
              // Add an empty file.
              FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
              fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
              fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
              fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
              uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

              // Start upload by uploading the first slice.
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
              {
                // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
                bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
                fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
              }

              // You can only start the upload once.
              first = false;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if (last)
            {
              // Is this the last slice of data?
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(lastBuffer))
              {
                // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
                uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                return uploadFile;
              }
            }
            else
            {
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
              {
                // Continue sliced upload.
                bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                // Update fileoffset for the next slice.
                fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
              }
            }
          }
        } // while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      if (fs != null)
      {
        fs.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

This is the first page where i run the method

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Contoso.Core.LargeFileUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Request Office365 site from the user
            string siteUrl = @"https://bundegruppen.sharepoint.com/sites/F24-2905/";

            /* Prompt for Credentials */
            //Console.WriteLine("Filer blir overført til site: {0}", siteUrl);
            string userName = "xx.xx@bxxbygg.no";
            SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
            string password = "xxx";
            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);

            /* End Program if no Credentials */
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || (pwd == null))
                return;

            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);


            // These should both work as expected.
            try
            {
                // Alternative 3 for uploading large files: slice per slice which allows you to stop and resume a download
                new FileUploadService().UploadFileSlicePerSliceToFolder(ctx, "Dokumenter/General", @"C:\Temp\F24_Sammenstillingsmodell.smc");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception while uploading files to the target site: {0}.", ex.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue.");
                Console.Read();
            }
            // Just to see what we have in console
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Exception while uploading files to the target site: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: List Dokumenter/General does not exsist in the URL-adress

Comment: I am trying too set libaryName = Dokumenter/General
List docs = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);

When i only write "Dokumenter" it works. But i want the file in the subfolder

Comment: What value are you passing in for libraryName? Are you passing "Documents/Folder1/folder2/"?

Comment: All i want to do is upload one big file too a specific sharepoint folder.
If someone have another way shorter code im up for that haha.

Comment: @willman Yes i am, i know its wrong too do it like that but dont know how to get it how i want :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have is written just to upload the specified file to the RootFolder of the named Library.  If you pass in a full path to a folder instead of just a Library Name, it will fail.
The following is a modded version of the function that should allow you to pass a full serverRelativeUrl to the desired folder:

```
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File UploadFileSlicePerSliceToFolder(ClientContext ctx, string serverRelativeFolderUrl, string fileName, int fileChunkSizeInMB = 3)
{
  // Each sliced upload requires a unique ID.
  Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();

  // Get the name of the file.
  string uniqueFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

  // Get the folder to upload into.
  Folder uploadFolder = ctx.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeFolderUrl);

  // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
  ctx.Load(uploadFolder);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();

  // File object.
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = null;

  // Calculate block size in bytes.
  int blockSize = fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024;

  // Get the information about the folder that will hold the file.
  ctx.Load(uploadFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();


  // Get the size of the file.
  long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;

  if (fileSize <= blockSize)
  {
    // Use regular approach.
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
      FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
      fileInfo.ContentStream = fs;
      fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
      fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
      uploadFile = uploadFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
      ctx.Load(uploadFile);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
      return uploadFile;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Use large file upload approach.
    ClientResult<long> bytesUploaded = null;

    FileStream fs = null;
    try
    {
      fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
      using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
      {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
        Byte[] lastBuffer = null;
        long fileoffset = 0;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;
        bool first = true;
        bool last = false;

        // Read data from file system in blocks.
        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
          totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

          // You've reached the end of the file.
          if (totalBytesRead == fileSize)
          {
            last = true;
            // Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size.
            lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
          }

          if (first)
          {
            using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
              // Add an empty file.
              FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
              fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
              fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
              fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
              uploadFile = uploadFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

              // Start upload by uploading the first slice.
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
              {
                // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
                bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
                fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
              }

              // You can only start the upload once.
              first = false;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if (last)
            {
              // Is this the last slice of data?
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(lastBuffer))
              {
                // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload.
                uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                // Return the file object for the uploaded file.
                return uploadFile;
              }
            }
            else
            {
              using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
              {
                // Continue sliced upload.
                bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                // Update fileoffset for the next slice.
                fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
              }
            }
          }
        } // while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      if (fs != null)
      {
        fs.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: i get an error with "rootweb" do i have too import something?

Comment: Sorry that should have been a reference to the Web in the current Context.  I have updated the code in the answer.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS MAN U DA KING!